# What is id value in the following code?What is exactly id generating?Does it generates choice 1 or only 1?

Tags: python, html, django

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}

        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">

        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that **question.choice_set.all** has 4 items.

```
[
    {"id": 0, "choice_text": "Choice 1"},
    {"id": 1, "choice_text": "Choice 2"},
    {"id": 2, "choice_text": "Choice 3"},
    {"id": 3, "choice_text": "Choice 4"},
]
```

The resulting code will look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" value="0">
<label for="choice1">Choice 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2" value="1">
<label for="choice2">Choice 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice3" value="2">
<label for="choice3">Choice 3</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice4" value="3">
<label for="choice4">Choice 4</label><br>
```